# How to Fix the format in textbox

Tags: vb.net

How can I fix my format in my textbox because sometimes my output is not giving me the right format so that it cannot be read in my database.

Sample output in my textbox:

```
Sample problem 1
Textbox7.text = 01.0107/23/2014 or ##.####/##/#### 
it should be:
Textbox7.text = 01.01 07/23/2014 or ##.## ##/##/####

Sample problem 2
Textbox7.text = 01.017/23/2014 or ##.###/##/####
it should be:
Textbox7.text = 01.01 07/23/2014 or ##.## ##/##/####

Sample problem 3
Textbox7.text = 01.07/23/2014 or ##.###/##/####
it should be:
Textbox7.text = 01.00 07/23/2014 or ##.## ##/##/####
```

It should have a space " " before my dateformat.

This is my current condition code but not functioning:

```
If TextBox7.Text = Format((TextBox7.Text), "##.####/##/####") Then
    TextBox7.Text = Format((TextBox7.Text), "##.## ##/##/####")

ElseIf TextBox7.Text = Format((TextBox7.Text), "##.###/##/####") Then
    TextBox7.Text = Format((TextBox7.Text), "##.## ##/##/####")
Else
    TextBox7.Text = Format((TextBox7.Text), "##.## ##/##/####")
End If
```

Comment: what is the "##.##" data before the date?  it looks like there are 2 pieces of information there, as well as the wrong [format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: it is a numeric value which always contains two numbers(##) then decimal point(.) then two numbers(##) then space(" ") then date format (mm/dd/yyyy)(##/##/####). And my problem is format is not consistent, so that I am having a problem how to fix. The solution is have a always execute  format like this ##.## ##/##/#### or 00.00 00/00/0000

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF? Is there a reason you're not using a MaskedTextBox instead, where you can specify the allowed format to start with and avoid all of this code noise? And why are you trying to store those two numbers and a date value in the same column, which is a bad idea? You should be storing them separately, and store the date value in a DateTime column and let the database worry about how to actually store it. (The thing you should learn is "If you're really struggling to get it to work, you're probably doing something wrong." Doing it right is much easier.)

Comment: why display 2 different pieces of info in one input control?  DateTime formatting would be simple without this other thing.  Try "##.## MM/dd/yyyy" as described in the link.  the other issue I'd be worried about is validating dates which are embedded with some other data.

Comment: Ahh, in my Form I have 3 textbox, lets call my project date time(military time with this format HH.mm ) calculator. example textbox1 + textbox2 = textbox3.   01.00 07/22/2014 + 24.00  =     01.00 07/23/2014 but sometimes my output is like this 01.0007/23/2014 or 01.07/23/2014 sometimes correct the output is not consistent.

Comment: ALL I need is to have a consistent format sir like this 00.00 00/00/000. My only problem is always have a space before the date format at the right.

Comment: Then you need to study that link in the first comment.  That timedate format would be "HH:mm MM/dd/yyyy" add "tt" if you need AM/PM.  That mask will also work to parse the text: `TextBox9.Text = myDate.Tostring("HH:mm MM/dd/yyyy")` will work wonderfully

Comment: Ok the what if I have a value 00.00 MM/dd/YYYY and I only want the date format I want get the right only then compare the two date format, can you give me initial code how can I the the first value before date format will not include

Comment: Example I have two value textbox1 = 00.00 01/01/2014 texbox2 = 00.00 01/01/2013 textbox 3 should have comparing the date format only then the others will be deny or not part of comparison.

Comment: the BEST way to do that would be to use the Text control for the Date and 2 NumericUpDowns for the time; that way the time portion would always be valid and it would be easier to compare the date parts because thats all that would be there is date data.  And the correct format is **MM/dd/yyyy** date format strings are case sensitive; it is how it can tell Month (MM) from Minutes (mm).

Comment: Could you give me an example? or much better simple date comparison from the right priority date the month then day. the other value deny

Comment: if Strings.Right(TextBox1.Text.Trim, 11) > Strings.Right(TextBox2.Text.Trim, 11) then. But I cannot compare them as date.

Comment: there are HUNDREDS of [examples at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime(v=vs.110).aspx) your question has changed into something very different in comments and I cannot answer a comment.  Use a DateTime variable to compare Dates - `Strings.Right(...` will **not** compare dates correctly and the stuff in a TextBox is not a Date, it is Text/String.  See [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

After all comments, this answer assume you insist to use your current input method for some reason and the input is always:

**FirstDate:** HH.mm MM/dd/yyyy **SecondDate** HH.mm

Before that: I don't think your IF statement will work. The comparison is always false for all condition. unless you key in ##.## ##/##/#### ?

```
If TextBox7.Text = Format((TextBox7.Text), "##.## ##/##/####") Then
```

[image]

Try this?

```
Private Sub SumDate()
    Dim firstDate As New DateTime
    Dim sumDate As New DateTime

    Dim firstDateString As String = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:00.00 00/00/0000}", TextBox1.Text)
    Dim secondDateString As String = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:00.00}", TextBox2.Text)

    firstDate = DateTime.ParseExact(firstDateString, "HH.mm MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

    Dim timeParts As String() = secondDateString.Split(".")

    Dim totalHours As Integer = timeParts(0)
    'Update: this allow the input of (30) or (30.00) by checking the length of timeParts
    Dim totalMins As Integer = 0
    If timeParts.Length = 2 Then totalMins = timeParts(1)

    sumDate = firstDate.AddHours(totalHours).AddMinutes(totalMins)

    TextBox3.Text = sumDate.ToString("HH.mm MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
End Sub
```

Comment: 21.56 07/22/2014 + 20.15   = 18.12 07/23/2014  The program is just like a military time date calculator

Comment: as I have mentioned in the code **'show error msg or do some calculation accordingly** when it's >24, just do some calculation accordingly. take the value and mod by 24 then use the value

Comment: Check updated answer. This would work even if you input dateformat + 100.56 . **Again, this is a strongly typed solution**. Feel free to change your input method as suggested by others in your question previously

Comment: So it only accept 24 in HH.mm format., In my program the max is 48 so that it means plus 2 days. for example 20.00 07/25/2014 + 30.00 = 02.00 07/27/2014.

Comment: can you make it until 50?

Comment: check updated code.. it accept input of (50) or (50.00)